# STM32H7 Changing boot1 adress in OBFlash

Tags: stm32, stm32h743

I am having troubles changing boot1 address in Option Byte in Flash

I want to change boot1 address, allowing me to launch either in bootloader mode (system memory) or usercode mode(flash) without using a jump.

I am currently testing on the STM32H743 EVAL Board

Here is the code changing the address and it does not appear its changing anything

```
HAL_FLASH_OB_Unlock();
HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
 
/* Change Boot0 address */
 
if(mode)OBInit.BootAddr1 = BOOTLOADER_ADDR0;
else OBInit.BootAddr1 = USER_CODE_ADDR0;
HAL_FLASHEx_OBProgram(&OBInit);
 
if (HAL_FLASH_OB_Launch() != HAL_OK)
{
    return(-1);//error
}
 
HAL_FLASH_OB_Lock();
HAL_FLASH_Lock();
```

Thanks,

Gabriel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed :
added
`OBInit.BootConfig=OB_BOOT_ADD1;`
before
`if(mode)OBInit.BootAddr1 = BOOTLOADER_ADDR0;`

Comment: looks to me like you are also missing `OBInit.OptionType = OPTIONBYTE_BOOTADD`